# When do we receive : "Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction] "?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-invocation, etherscan

I have received same message as this question :
[Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28428/warning-error-encountered-during-contract-execution-bad-instruction)
However, my contract concept is different. Here is my contract code :

```
pragma solidity 0.4.23; 

contract RFID {

    struct StateStruct {
        bytes32 description;
        mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) sub_state;
    }

    struct ObjectStruct {
        StateStruct state;
        address owner; 
        bool isObject;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => ObjectStruct) objectStructs;
    bytes32[] public objectList;

    event LogNewObject(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values, address owner);
    event LogChangeObjectState(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values);
    event LogChangeObjectOwner(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, address newOwner);

    function isObject(bytes32 _id) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
        return objectStructs[_id].isObject;
    }

    function getObjectCount() public view returns(uint count) {
        return objectList.length;
    }

    /*function setArraySize(uint256 _number_of_sub_states) public {

        number_of_sub_states = _number_of_sub_states;

    }

    function getArraySize() view public returns (uint256) {
       return number_of_sub_states;
    }*/

    function newObject(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values, address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(!isObject(_id));

        uint256 counter=0;
        for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

            objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

            emit LogNewObject(msg.sender, _id, bytes32(sub_states_types[counter]), bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]), _owner);

        }

        objectStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
        objectStructs[_id].isObject = true;

        objectList.push(_id);

        return true;
    }

    function changeObjectState(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values) public returns(bool success) {
        require(isObject(_id));
        uint256 counter=0;
        for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

            objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

            emit LogChangeObjectState(msg.sender, _id, bytes32(sub_states_types[counter]), bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]));

        }
        //objectStructs[_id].state = StateStruct(_newState);
        //emit LogChangeObjectState(msg.sender, _id, _newState);
        return true;
    }

    function changeObjectOwner(bytes32 _id, address _newOwner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(isObject(_id));
        objectStructs[_id].owner = _newOwner;
        emit LogChangeObjectOwner(msg.sender, _id, _newOwner);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And I invoked `function newObject` as follows :

```
> web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773', 'logic');
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> contractInstance.methods.newObject(web3.utils.asciiToHex("50"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("3"),[web3.utils.asciiToHex("location"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("price"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("sold"),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex("")],[web3.utils.asciiToHex("Paris"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("50"),web3.utils.asciiToHex("No"),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex(""),web3.utils.asciiToHex("")], '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773').send({ from: '0xE07b6e5a2026CC916A4E2Beb03767ae0ED6af773' }, function(error, result) {
...     console.log(error);
...     console.log(result)
... });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: undefined,
  emit: [Function: emit],
  on: [Function: on],
  once: [Function: once],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  listeners: [Function: listeners],
  addListener: [Function: on],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners] }
> null
0xa270ed1bda636e4256327683c8d4e5689d81d44c0536a78d4acdb295c9d778e2
(node:11166) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:
{
  "blockHash": "0x82f1d259bc06749c886016e978152d11c65730dd8b1a6388e738fca620db5be7",
  "blockNumber": 4286599,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 965036,
  "gasUsed": 940000,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "root": null,
  "status": false,
```

I got transaction hash. However, when I search transaction status in https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/tx/0xa270ed1bda636e4256327683c8d4e5689d81d44c0536a78d4acdb295c9d778e2

It is mentioned : **"Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]"**

**When, I invoke `function newObject` with *remix*, it works without any problem.**

**Is there any problem in my contract ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a call to your contract with:

```
contractInstance.methods.newObject(
    web3.utils.asciiToHex("50"),
    web3.utils.asciiToHex("3"),...
```

In your contract it is declared

```
function newObject(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, ..)
```

But `web3.utils.asciiToHex("3")` returns `0x33`. Meaning `number_of_sub_states = 51` in your function. This causes an index out of bound when trying to access elements beyond 10 in your function.

You can either pass numbers directly

```
contractInstance.methods.newObject(
    web3.utils.asciiToHex("50"),
    3,
```

Or use [`web3.utils.toHex()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#tohex)

```
contractInstance.methods.newObject(
    web3.utils.asciiToHex("50"),
    web3.utils.toHex("3"),
```